# How do we deduce that $c_1=c_2=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

**Theorem**

The boundary value problem $$y''+p_1(x) y'+ p_2(x)=f(x)(1)\\ a_1 y(x_0)+a_2 y'(x_0)= b_1 y(x_1)+b_2 y'(x_1)=0 (2)$$

has a unique solution iff  the corresponding homogeneous problem ( $f \equiv 0$) has only the trivial solution.

**Proof**

The solution of the equation is $y=y_{\mu}+ c_1 y_1+ c_2 y_2 (3)$

where $y_{\mu}$ is a solution of the non-homogeneous equation and  $y_1, y_2$ are linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous problem.

Replacing $(3)$ at $(2)$ we get the following system as for $c_1, c_2$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 y_1(x_0)+a_2 y_1'(x_0) & a_1 y_2(x_0)+a_2 y_2'(x_0) \\ 
b_1 y_1(x_1)+b_2 y_1'(x_1) & b_1 y_2(x_1)+b_2 y_2'(x_1) 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
c_1\\ 
c_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-a_1 y_{\mu}(x_0)-a_2 y_{\mu}'(x_0)\\ 
-b_1 y_{\mu}(x_1)-b_2 y_{\mu}'(x_1)
\end{pmatrix}$$

which has a unique solution , iff the determinant of the matrix of coefficients is non-zero. But if this determinantis different from $0$, the corresponding homogeneous problem has only trivial solution, since we will have $c_1=c_2=0$.

Could you explain to me how from the fact that the matrix of coefficients is non-zero, we deduce that $c_1=c_2=0$

Comment: For the homogeneous problem $y_\mu=0$, so the rhs of the system vanishes and the solution is $c_1=c_2=0$.

Comment: @Aretino Ah, I see... Thank you!!!